# How to make apt-maven-plugin work with java 8

Tags: java, java-8, maven-3

I am migrating from java 6 to java 8. I have a maven project and it has apt-maven-plugin which is not running on jdk 1.8. Do we have a workaround or an alternate to make it work with java 8? Is it possible to run apt-maven-plugin with java 8??
Please find below the maven entry:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <factory>
                        com.emc.tsg.common.xml.ABCGenerator
                    </factory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/model/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
and i have changed the maven tools.jar dependency for java 8 as:
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
I have changed the java version as:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When i am trying to run mvn compile, i am getting apt compiler not found error. I think in jdk tools.jar there is no apt class unlike java 6 hence wondering if at all its possible to achieve this in java 8?

Comment: This may not be the problem, but why are you using version 1.0-alpha-3 when 1.1.3 is the latest version?

Comment: Thanks David..changed the version also.. but that is not helping either.